# Download data from Mapbox Tilequery API

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-api-tilequery

Is there a way to download bulk data from Mapbox Tilequery API? I need to download GeoJSON points of buildings in a given area, say the whole San Francisco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tilequery API has a `limit` parameter which specifies the number of features to return for a given API request. As indicated in the documentation [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#tilequery), the `limit` cannot be more than 50, so bulk downloading of feature data is not possible.

It is worth taking a look at the [Mapbox Terms of Service](https://www.mapbox.com/legal/tos), which indicate some limitations on the downloading/caching of Mapbox data. Much of Mapbox building data is provided via [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/), so you could instead consider following [this guide](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/overpass-turbo/) to use [Overpass Turbo](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/overpass-turbo/) to query OpenStreetMap data and extract specific building features in a given area.